# How to load a sublevel JSON file into DynamoDB using Boto3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I got problems trying to load my JSON file into AWS dynamoDB with Python and Boto3, when this file have a sublevel json.

For exaple i have this code bellow:

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='sa-east-1', aws_access_key_id='AWS ACCESS KEY', aws_secret_access_key='AWS SECRET KEY')
table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Movies',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'year',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'title',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'year',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'title',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)

print("Table status:", table.table_status)
```

In this layout i create a table in AWS dynamoDB, but only for JSON on one level structure, like:

```
[
    {
        "year": 2013,
        "title": "Rush"
    }
]
```

But if i want to put a JSON file with sublevel? How i have to create this table with Boto3? And how to input the file? like this:

```
[
    {
        "year": 2013,
        "title": "Rush",
        "info": {
            "directors": ["Ron Howard"],
            "release_date": "2013-09-02T00:00:00Z",
            "rating": 8.3,
            "genres": [
                "Action",
                "Biography",
                "Drama",
                "Sport"
            ],
            "image_url": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQyMDE0MTY0OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjI2OTI0OQ@@._V1_SX400_.jpg",
            "plot": "A re-creation of the merciless 1970s rivalry between Formula One rivals James Hunt and Niki Lauda.",
            "rank": 2,
            "running_time_secs": 7380,
            "actors": [
                "Daniel Bruhl",
                "Chris Hemsworth",
                "Olivia Wilde"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I read Boto3 Docs and search some tutorials on the internet, but I can not find how to do this. It should be simple, I know I must have a way to do this, but I can not get it yet. Someone have some tip for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i have made a simple concept mistake. To DynamoDB, when you are creating a table, you don't need to declare every attribute of the table. In this phase, you just need to say who will be the Partition Key and the Sort Key (if it have one). If the items you imputing have more attributes, u can declare on put_item() function, like:

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import json
import decimal

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='sa-east-1', aws_access_key_id='AWS ACCESS KEY', aws_secret_access_key='AWS SECRET KEY')

table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')

title = "The Big New Movie"
year = 2015

response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'year': year,
        'title': title,
        'info': {
            'plot':"Nothing happens at all.",
            'rating': decimal.Decimal(0)
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using you example above, I think you can simply use the table.update_item() method.

```
key = {'year': '2013'},{'title': 'Rush'}
attribute_name = 'info'
attribute_value = {} # build your info as a dictionary
attribute_value['directors'] = ['Ron Howard']
...

response = table.update_item(
    Key = key,
    UpdateExpression="SET " + attribute_name + " = :val",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':val': attribute_value},
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you load this way, it will take care of the nested JSON structure, when you read it out, you can parse the JSON and read the required attribute in the JSON

```
import boto3
import json

dynamodbclient=boto3.resource('dynamodb')
sample_table = dynamodbclient.Table('ec2metadata')

with open('/samplepath/spotec2interruptionevent.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

# parse file
obj = json.loads(data)

#instance_id and cluster_id is the Key in dynamodb table 

    response=sample_table.put_item(
                              Item={
                                  'instance_id': instanceId,
                                  'cluster_id': clusterId,
                                  'event':obj

                              }
                              )
```